# Having trouble writing build.gradle with jar-specific tasks

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I've got the directory and file named src/main/java/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java.  And my build.gradle has:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
  }
}

task worldJar(type: Jar) {
  baseName = "WorldJar"

  from(sourceSets.main.output) {
    include "HelloWorld/**"
  }
}
```

but, the jar that is produced doesn't have HelloWorld.class in it.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use `java` plugin when you use standard project layout?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate packages and do this:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
  }
}

task worldJar(type: Jar) {
  baseName = "WorldJar"

  println sourceSets.main.output
  from(sourceSets.main.output) {
    include "HelloWorld/**"
  }
}

task spencerJar(type: Jar) {
  baseName = "SpencerJar"

  from(sourceSets.main.output) {
    include "HelloSpencer/**"
  }
}
```